# Graphical Finite State Machine Editor

Tags: code-generation, fsm

I am looking for a sophisticated graphical FSM editor that can export a model in a well-documented output format, like SCXML or similar.

Can anybody recommend me a tool?

Comment: the stack overflow community does not seem very interested in MDA?!

Comment: I made this a while back http://memention.com/designer/

Comment: This should be reopened, closing makes no sense.

Comment: Someone has to make a StackExchange website specifically for questions like the one above. Too many good questions are being closed as "off topic" on THIS website, but there doesn't seem to be any OTHER website to ask them instead :P

Answer (score 17):

I am only just now starting to look at [YAKINDU](http://www.statecharts.org/index.html) - it looks like it might be a great graphical FSM tool built on top of the Eclipse framework, and has (IIUC) automatic code generation for the state graph.

Answer (score 14):

I found this pretty interesting software

> DRAKON is a visual language for specifications from the Russian space program. DRAKON is used for capturing requirements and building software that controls spacecraft.

http://drakon-editor.sourceforge.net/

It is advanced software. It can generate ERlang, as well as many other languages, state machine code. http://drakon-editor.sourceforge.net/erlang_auto.html

It's free / OSX / Windows

[image: Screenshot] .

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure if this is excactly what you are looking for but seeing as there aren't too many answers to your question I'll throw it out there. [Ragel](http://www.complang.org/ragel/) is a finite state machine compiler which will output C/C++/Java and more. It's not visual per se (you can't design the state machine graphically, you use code) but it is able to use [GraphViz](http://graphviz.org/) to visualise the state machine.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to generate code (C++ or Python), [fsme](http://fsme.sourceforge.net/) does a very good job.  I have successfully used it to create a number of very complex state machines, and would use it again for anything similar.

Answer (score 3):

The QM tool available here http://www.state-machine.com/qm/index.php is a nice UML statemachine editor and code generator, that generates C/C++ code, but for QP kernels.

Answer (score 3):

Check out http://madebyevan.com/fsm/ its quite easy to use and it even produces LaTeX!

Comment: But there is no way to save the output in a format that an engine can use

Answer (score 2):

you can use [Stateflow](http://www.mathworks.com/products/stateflow/) to draw and simulate graphical state machines. It also provides an interface for creating state transition tables. The model can then be exported as html reports and can emit C/C++ code for implementation.

Comment: You should call it $tateflow since it requires MATLAB and Simulink.

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://code.google.com/p/scxmlgui/) project seems to be spot on, but I'm not sure about the status...

Answer (score 0):

this may work for you: http://fsme.sourceforge.net/

it is kind of old, but better give a try;)

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple UI builder for scxml charts available on google code 
Try here
http://code.google.com/p/scxmlgui/

Seems to be quite active